# How to embed a Python window into HTML

Tags: python, html

I want to embed a Python text-based game that I made into HTML, but I am having trouble finding out how.

I searched around Google for embeddable Python windows and such but couldn't find anything. I want it to be like embedding a game or video into my site.

Comment: `flask`, `django` & `fastapi` frameworks come to mind...

Comment: this is not yet an actual coding question as you need to show what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is not terribly difficult to do.  Just remember the user isn't running Python.  You can't "embed" Python in a web site.  He's just talking to your web site.  Your web site can open a Python instance, feed in interactive lines, read the output, and send the results back to the browser.

Comment: Do you mean [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/)?